# Python parse Chinese email decode Error

Tags: python, decode

I wrote some Python codes to get emails from Gmail server. Here are the code below:

```
self.M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(self.IMAP_SERVER, self.IMAP_PORT)
data = self.M.fetch(id,"(RFC822)")
if data[0] == 'OK':
    msg = email.message_from_string(data[1][0][1])
else:
    print 'Error!'
mail_subject = email.Header.decode_header(msg['subject'])[0][0]
print email.Header.decode_header(msg['subject'])
print '~~~separator~~~'
print mail_subject
```

English mails subject displayed correctly:

```
[('[bonnshore.github.com] Page build successful', None)]

~~~separator~~~

[bonnshore.github.com] Page build successful
```

but after Chinese instead:

```
[('\xd5\xe2\xca\xc7\xd6\xd0\xce\xc4\xb2\xe2\xca\xd4\xa3\xa1', 'gb2312')]

~~~separator~~~

╒Γ╩╟╓╨╬─▓Γ╩╘úí
```

Function isinstance() showed the type of character is 'str',
So I tryed this to solve it:

```
print unicode(mail_subject, 'gb2312')
```

and occur an error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6:
character maps to <undefined>
```

I also tryed to decode the character directly:

```
print mail_subject.decode("gb2312")
```

and I got the same error again!

So, How to fix this?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Are you sure that the data is actually encoded in `gb2312`? There's a reason that decode_header returns a tuple including the actually used encoding ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt displays as [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) because you are printing raw gb2312 to a non-gb2312 console. `decode_header` does the first part of the job, which is converting a header that looks like `=?iso-8859-1?q?p=F6stal?=` into something that can be shown to the user. Since the same header can contain multiple charsets, what you get out is a list of (`raw_data`, `charset`) pairs.

You're supposed to convert them to Unicode — and then to UTF-8 or whatever suits your needs — using the Unicode constructor, as you correctly guessed. But your second attempt failed because code page 437 is unable to display Chinese. Your third problem comes from a misunderstanding of the direction in which `decode` and `encode` work. A unicode string is "encoded" to an external encoding. (But even if that succeeded, you would still be back to the original mojibake of printing gb2312 to your terminal.)

To test the result, you will need to correctly create a Unicode string and inspect it or print it to a file with the correct encoding. For example:

```
>>> x = unicode('\xd5\xe2\xca\xc7\xd6\xd0\xce\xc4\xb2\xe2\xca\xd4\xa3\xa1', 'gb2312')
>>> import unicodedata
>>> map(unicodedata.name, x)  # see if it looks chinese
['CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-8FD9', 'CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-662F', 'CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-4E2D', 'CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-6587', 'CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-6D4B', 'CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-8BD5', 'FULLWIDTH EXCLAMATION MARK']
>>> print x                   # this works for me because I'm in a UTF-8 locale
这是中文测试！
```

You can do this to test that it works for you:

```
>>> with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
...   f.write(x.encode('utf-8'))
```

Finally, note that getting the first item return by `decode_header` is insufficient to get the whole value of the header, because it can be split into several chunks. You need to join the chunks into a single Unicode string, which is best done by combining the `make_header` utility function and the `unicode` constructor:

```
subject_header = msg['subject']
subject = unicode(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(subject_header))
# now proceed as before...
```

It feels counterintuitive to have to call `make_header` and `decode_header`, but that is the current API, [fixed in Python 3](http://bugs.python.org/msg184896).

Comment: @bonn I just figured out that `Header` supports the unicode constructor, so you can just type `subject = unicode(msg['subject'])` to get the subject correctly decoded to Unicode.

Comment: @4815162342 I will try this solution later, it shall be OK either I guess...and the **terminal encode fault** you mentioned in your answer is exactly correct, so I changed the encode format to utf-8 supported, now I can use `email.Header.decode_header(subject)[0][0]` to get a proper email subject which were typed in Chinese.:)

Comment: @bonn `decode_header(subject)[0][0])` is simple, but incorrect. First, it will only give you the first part of the header (which can consist of several parts). Second, it will give you the raw data in whatever charset was used in the original header, **not** UTF-8. To get the full subject in UTF-8, use `unicode(subject).encode("utf-8")`.

Comment: @4815162342 The first reason you said convinced me, but the second is not works. I got stuff like `=?utf-8?B...Hkv6E=?=`, when use `unicode(msg['subject'])` or `unicode(msg['subject']).encode("utf-8")`.

Comment: @bonn You are correct, it doesn't work as expected. It would appear that `email.header.Header.__unicode__` doesn't attempt to decode the header. I have now updated the answer with an example of the correct invocation and [reported the bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue17505).

Comment: @4815162342 Hi! The part of the answer you updated is a strict way to solve this problem and it worked in most cases...but sometimes some emails were send without specified encode format then `email.header.decode_header(subject_header)` would return a `None` as the second returned value, this lead to the failure of `unicode(s,c)` function which needs 2 string arguments.

Comment: @bonn I've now updated the answer with the `make_header(decode_header(...))` idiom pointed out by R. David Murray in response to the [bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue17505), which should work in all cases.

Comment: @4815162342 Maybe I should open the bug link earlier, after all problem was solved. As a new Python user, I learned new knowledge through all of this. So thanks very much! :)